# How to order occurrences counting from 1 to n occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table that contains several columns, but for the task, the important ones are `id` end `created_date`, where `id` can repeat.

Sample data:

```
+--------+--------------+
|  id    | created_date |
+--------+--------------+
| 12345  | 2020-05-01   |
| 12345  | 2020-04-23   |
| 54321  | 2020-05-12   |
| 12345  | 2020-06-13   |
| 54321  | 2020-01-03   |
+--------+--------------+
```

I need to write a query that creates a new column that enumerate the occurrences of each `id`, ordered by the ascending `created_date`. The output must be something like the following:

```
+--------+--------------+------------------+
|  id    | created_date | occurrence_count |
+--------+--------------+------------------+
| 12345  | 2020-04-23   |                1 |
| 12345  | 2020-05-01   |                2 |
| 12345  | 2020-06-13   |                3 |
| 54321  | 2020-01-03   |                1 |
| 54321  | 2020-05-12   |                2 |
+--------+--------------+------------------+
```

What query would output this result table?

Comment: I don't have an attempt because I don't have a clue on how to do it. I am guessing that maybe I have to create a select where I count and group by ids and then use it to fill a column with the occurrence counting, but I realy don't have a clue on how to do...

Comment: The answer below is probably what you want. A scalar, correlated subquery does work, though less efficient: `(select count(*) from T t2 where t2.id = T.id and t2.created_date <= T.created_date)`

Comment: "I don't have an attempt".  So start attempting.

Comment: Are there duplicates? (multiple rows of same id and created_date) If so, how do want them handled?

Comment: @Dumbledore, as a matter of fact, in the original table where I would apply this query, the created_date is a timestamp. I used date as example to simplify the question. So, there are no duplicate rows, just duplicate ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use window function

```
select t.*,
   row_number() over (partition by id order by created_date asc) as occurrence_count
 from t
```

Comment: IF this answer is helpful for you, please consider to mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to count occurence:

```
SELECT id, 
       COUNT(id) AS [occurrence_count]
FROM Table 
GROUP by id
```

if you need the other columns as well, you can do it with a inner join

Comment: This is not the questioner is asking.